# laravel one-to-many on pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

I have a four table which are institutions, forms, form_institution(pivot table) and form_institution_attributes. Here is migrations :

Institution Table :

```
public function up() {
     Schema::create('institutions', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->increments('id');
         $table->string('name', 255);
         $table->softDeletes();
         $table->timestamps();
     });
 }
```

Institution model :

```
public function forms() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Form::class, 'form_institution');
}
```

Form Table :

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('forms', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 255);
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Form Model :

```
public function institutions() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Institution::class, 'form_institution');
}
```

Form Institution Pivot Table :

```
Schema::create('form_institution', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('institution_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('form_id')->unsigned();

    $table->foreign('institution_id')->references('id')->on('institutions');
    $table->foreign('form_id')->references('id')->on('forms');
});
```

Everything is ok till here. But i need to add one more table which is attribute table and it's relationship between pivot table (one-to-many)

Here is table :

```
Schema::create('form_institution_attributes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('form_institution_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('field_name_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('input_type_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('field_caption');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('form_institution_id')->references('id')->on('form_institution');
        });
```

Now, when i call the institution table and institution->forms parameter, i want to get form_institution_attribute (sub-table) with pivot table. But i couldn't do this ?

How can i add table under pivot table as a one-to-many relation ?

Comment: Firstly, you have some mistakes in your last migration file. You should be referencing the 'form_institution' table since an 'institution_form' table does not exist. Also, the naming of the 'institution_form_id' should be form_institution_id'. If you correct those it will be easier for people to help you out.

Comment: @OrestisPalampougioukis i missed it, i edited as a form_institution.

Comment: When you don't need an extra table, add the attributes directly in the pivot table. Do something like: `$this->belongsToMany(Form::class, 'form_institution')->withPivot('field_name_id', 'input_type_id', 'field_caption');` and define your columns finally in your migration file. [http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/](http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/)

Comment: @StevenSteinrücken which migration file ? Do i add field_name_id, input_type_id and field_caption columns to form_institution migration ?

Comment: @GoMommy you are right

Comment: @StevenSteinrücken it makes, multiple pivot for one institution but it works. I wanted to add under one pivot table. I do not know is this good approach.Can you write as an answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the [HasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) type of relationship.

However, I think the best solution would be to add these attributes to extra columns that you create in your 'form_institution' table and then retrieve them much more easily by adding the withPivot method to your relationship definitions.

So that would look like this:

```
public function forms() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Form::class, 'form_institution')
        ->withPivot([
            'field_name_id',
            'field_caption'.
            ...
        ]);
}

public function institutions() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Institution::class, 'form_institution')
        ->withPivot([
            'field_name_id',
            'field_caption'.
            ...
        ]);
}
```

Comment: it makes many pivot parameter under one institution. Is this good approaching ? I wanted to add many attributes under one pivot. But now, i have many pivot.

Comment: Firstly, I made an edit to my answer, suggesting you could probably also make use of a HasManyThrough relationship. However, I honestly do not see the problem with adding the attributes you need to the pivot table. There will be one and only pivot table, the one called 'form_institution', which will hold both the institution_id, the form_id as well as the "extra" attributes that you would otherwise insert to the new 'form_institution_attributes' table.

Comment: @OrestisPalampougioukis What if there are multiple instances of the attributes you want to add? For instance, in the OP's example, you have 2 attributes you want to associate with a form_institution instance, or you may have 5, or none.